# Ios Server-to-Server Notifications

Tags: ios, json, iphone, app-store-connect, receipt-validation

I am trying to implement the Server-to-Server Notifications for IOS subscriptions. I have went through the [Server-to-Server Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/enabling_server-to-server_notifications) documentation and followed all the necessary steps. My server is in the GCM.

Now when i do a purchase in the app i am getting the notification in my server, but the response is totally different from the which is defined in the above link.

The response which i am getting contains only one field that is **latest_receipt** . But in the documentation they have mentioned various parameters. So, i thought i have to verify the receipt by send a post message to this [endpoint](http://%20https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt) . Now i am getting a json body which contains lot of information, but still i am not getting the json which is mentioned in the documentation.

The response body i am getting after verifying the purchase ( https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt)

```
{
  "auto_renew_status": 1,
  "status": 0,
  "auto_renew_product_id": " ",
  "receipt": {
    "original_purchase_date_pst": "2019-01-09 01:26:35 America/Los_Angeles",
    "quantity": "1",
    "unique_vendor_identifier": " ",
    "bvrs": "56",
    "expires_date_formatted": "2019-07-18 06:19:17 Etc/GMT",
    "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",
    "purchase_date_ms": "1563430577000",
    "expires_date_formatted_pst": "2019-07-17 23:19:17 America/Los_Angeles",
    "is_trial_period": "false",
    "item_id": "1298435177",
    "unique_identifier": " ",
    "original_transaction_id": "1000000492823158",
    "expires_date": "1563430757000",
    "transaction_id": "1000000548145129",
    "web_order_line_item_id": "1000000045717939",
    "version_external_identifier": "0",
    "bid": " ",
    "product_id": " ",
    "purchase_date": "2019-07-18 06:16:17 Etc/GMT",
    "original_purchase_date": "2019-01-09 09:26:35 Etc/GMT",
    "purchase_date_pst": "2019-07-17 23:16:17 America/Los_Angeles",
    "original_purchase_date_ms": "1547025995000"
  },
  "latest_receipt_info": {
    "original_purchase_date_pst": "2019-01-09 01:26:35 America/Los_Angeles",
    "unique_identifier": " ",
    "original_transaction_id": "1000000492823158",
    "expires_date": "1563430757000",
    "transaction_id": "1000000548145129",
    "quantity": "1",
    "product_id": " ",
    "bvrs": "56",
    "bid": " ",
    "unique_vendor_identifier": " ",
    "web_order_line_item_id": "1000000045717939",
    "original_purchase_date_ms": "1547025995000",
    "expires_date_formatted": "2019-07-18 06:19:17 Etc/GMT",
    "purchase_date": "2019-07-18 06:16:17 Etc/GMT",
    "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",
    "purchase_date_ms": "1563430577000",
    "expires_date_formatted_pst": "2019-07-17 23:19:17 America/Los_Angeles",
    "is_trial_period": "false",
    "purchase_date_pst": "2019-07-17 23:16:17 America/Los_Angeles",
    "original_purchase_date": "2019-01-09 09:26:35 Etc/GMT",
    "item_id": "1298435177"
  }
}
```

But in the documentation they have mentioned :

```
 environment
 notification_type
 password
 cancellation_date
 cancellation_date_pst
 cancellation_date_ms
 web_order_line_item_id
 latest_receipt
 latest_receipt_info
 latest_expired_receipt
 latest_expired_receipt_info
 auto_renew_status
 auto_renew_product_id
 auto_renew_status_change_date
 auto_renew_status_change_date_pst
 auto_renew_status_change_date_ms
```

I am not getting the main fields such as **environment and  notification_type**.

Whats wrong in it ?

For the first time this is the response i am getting

```
{ latest_receipt: 'ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZ'}
```

The response which i am getting from the server 2 server notification is on the second time (once its renewed):

```
{ environment: 'Sandbox',
  auto_renew_status: 'false',
  latest_expired_receipt: 'ewoJIn'
}
```

Comment: Hi, I would like to know how you handled and tested the S2S notification in the backend. I'm trying to implement the same in case of non-renewing subscription. I've provided the url in the app store for notification but I'm not getting any response when I try to do a test purchase using sandbox.

Comment: @VinayN S2S notifications are only for auto-renewable subscriptions. Kindly refer to this documentation .
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/enabling_app_store_server_notifications

Answer (score 3):

The parameters you get when you set up server 2 server notification are not exactly in the same format (or contains the same fields) as when you query verifyReceipt.

For example environment and notification_type are available only in the server 2 server notification and not in verifyReceipt.

Here is an example of the complete params you get when apple send you a notification with the server 2 server notifications -

```
    {
    "latest_receipt": "ewoXXXXX",
    "latest_receipt_info": {
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "2019-07-29 21:13:18 America/Los_Angeles",
        "quantity": "1",
        "unique_vendor_identifier": "XXX",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "1564459998000",
        "expires_date_formatted": "2019-08-06 04:13:17 Etc/GMT",
        "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",
        "purchase_date_ms": "1564459997000",
        "expires_date_formatted_pst": "2019-08-05 21:13:17 America/Los_Angeles",
        "is_trial_period": "true",
        "item_id": "1452171111",
        "unique_identifier": "00000",
        "original_transaction_id": "0000000",
        "expires_date": "00000000",
        "app_item_id": "0000000",
        "transaction_id": "00000000",
        "bvrs": "00000",
        "web_order_line_item_id": "00000000",
        "version_external_identifier": "000000",
        "bid": "com.XXX",
        "product_id": "XXXXX",
        "purchase_date": "2019-07-30 04:13:17 Etc/GMT",
        "purchase_date_pst": "2019-07-29 21:13:17 America/Los_Angeles",
        "original_purchase_date": "2019-07-30 04:13:18 Etc/GMT"
    },
    "environment": "PROD",
    "auto_renew_status": "true",
    "password": "*****",
    "auto_renew_product_id": "com.XXXX",
    "notification_type": "INITIAL_BUY"
}
```

Your example is from a verifyReceipt response.

The documentation is not that great about server 2 server notification but the latest wwdc video is great - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/302/

Note that quite a few of the fields in this payload are considered deprecated by now.

Comment: I understand that, but i am not getting the above response as you mentioned. I have edited the question to show what response i am getting in the server 2 server notification

Comment: So you do get the environment in the S2S notification. Have you tried to look at none sandbox responses?

Comment: No, that too i am getting this response once the subscription is renewed. At the first when i purchase the subscription i am getting only the latest_receipt.

Comment: I don't understand, you clearly say "The response which i am getting from the server 2 server notification is:" and then you have a response that include the environment so why are you saying you don't see the environment field for s2s notifications?

Comment: I am sorry for that, that response i am getting for the second time once subscription is getting renewed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Finally i have got that working.